# How to push an object?

Tags: unity, physics

I would like to "push" an object using a raycast.
With the following code, the problem is that depending of player rotation, i don't push the object but i pull it.

What am i wrong ?

```
Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
if (Physics.Raycast (RayCastSpawnOut.transform.position, fwd, out hit, 5)) {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "MyObjectTag") {   
                    GameObject myobj = hit.transform.gameObject;
                    Rigidbody myobj_rb = myobj.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
                    Vector3 dir = transform.position - myobj_rb.transform.position;
                    dir.Normalize(); //Normalize to get the correct direction
                    myobj_rb.AddRelativeForce (dir * 0.5f, ForceMode.Impulse);  
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Lets look at the math:

We'll assume that the universe is 1 dimesnional and your player object exists at `5` while the object you want to push exists at `6`.

You fire a ray, it hits the object, we get the rigidbody and then we perform this calculation:

```
dir = transform.position - myobj_rb.transform.position
```

What is the value of `dir` in our one dimensional universe?  Why, -1:

`5` minus `6` is `-1`

We then normalize (no change) and then apply that force to the object:

```
myobj_rb.AddRelativeForce (dir * 0.5f, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

But the force is negative, pulling it towards the player!

Comment: So the answer is "Abs" , right ?

Comment: @stighy No. Do the math again with the player at `6` and the object at `5`. You'll find that the impulse in that case is positive, but again, pulling it towards the player.

Comment: You're right. I've solved using AddForce and as 'direction' i've used this " Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);"

Comment: @sighy or a short form of `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)`, which is available as just `transform.forward`

Comment: Or reverse the math... `dir = myobj_rb.transform.position - transform.position`